Camera topics visible in topic visualization, but not in `ros2 topic list` -- [Ros2, Gazebo Classic]
I've spent way too long trying to figure this out so any help would be really appreciated.
I am working on porting a simulation setup over to ros2 from ros1. I am using the PX4 Gazebo Classic simulation. I am able to launch the simulation with my own world and robot defined in iris_depth_camera.sdf:
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version='1.5'>
  <model name='iris_depth_camera'>
    <include>
      <uri>model://iris</uri>
      <pose> 0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
    </include>

    <include>
      <uri>model://camera1_l</uri>
      <pose>0.12 0.045 0.01 0 0 0</pose>
    </include>
    <include>
      <uri>model://camera1_r</uri>
      <pose>0.12 -0.045 0.01 0 0 0 0</pose>
    </include>

    <!-- ||||||||||  camera1  |||||||||||||||-->
    <joint name="camera1_l_joint" type="revolute">
      <child>camera1_l::link</child>
      <parent>iris::base_link</parent>
      <axis>
        <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
        <limit>
          <upper>0</upper>
          <lower>0</lower>
        </limit>
      </axis>
    </joint>
    <joint name="camera1_r_joint" type="revolute">
      <child>camera1_r::link</child>
      <parent>iris::base_link</parent>
      <axis>
        <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
        <limit>
          <upper>0</upper>
          <lower>0</lower>
        </limit>
      </axis>
    </joint>
  </model>
</sdf>


Here is one of the camera sdf's:
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.5">
  <model name="camera1_l">
    <link name="link">
      <pose>0.0 0.0 0.035 0 0 0</pose>
      <inertial>
        <mass>0.005</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.000166667</ixx>
          <iyy>0.000166667</iyy>
          <izz>0.000166667</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
      <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.01 0.01 0.01</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <!-- <visual name="visual">
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.01 0.01 0.01</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </visual> -->
      <sensor name="camera" type="camera">
        <!-- <update_rate>30.0</update_rate> -->
        <camera>
          <!-- <pose>0.1 0.035 0 0 0 0</pose> -->
          <!-- <horizontal_fov>3.5962634</horizontal_fov>
          <cutoff_angle>3.56888668</cutoff_angle> -->
          <horizontal_fov>1.462634</horizontal_fov>
          <image>
            <width>400</width>
            <height>400</height>
            <format>R8G8B8</format>
          </image>
          <clip>
            <near>0.02</near>
            <far>300</far>
          </clip>
          <noise>
            <type>gaussian</type>
            <mean>0.0</mean>
            <stddev>0.007</stddev>
          </noise>
        </camera>
        <plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
          <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
          <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
          <cameraName>stereo1/left</cameraName>
          <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
          <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
          <frameName>camera_link1</frameName>
          <!-- <distortionK1>-0.0155</distortionK1> -->
          <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
          <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
          <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
          <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
          <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
        </plugin>
      </sensor>
    </link>
  </model>

</sdf>


The camera feeds come up just fine in the Gazebo topic visualizer:

But, when I run ros2 topic list, I only get
/parameter_events
/rosout

If anybody could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it so much.
Thanks!

You stated you are using Gazebo classic. How are you starting it?
You should use the gazebo_ros package to make sure gz topics are published in ros.
e.g., in a ros2 launchfile:
ld.add_action(launch.actions.IncludeLaunchDescription(
    PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
      os.path.join(gazebo_ros, 'launch', 'gzserver.launch.py')
    ),
    launch_arguments={
      'verbose': 'True',
      'world': params['world'],
      'paused': 'false',
      'init': 'true',
      'factory': 'true',
      'force_system': 'true',
      'params_file': os.path.join(summit_xl_gazebo, 'config','gazebo.yml'),
    }.items(),
  ))

Otherwise if using "new" Gazebo you have to explicitly bridge topics:
https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/migrating_gazebo_classic_ros2_packages
